# RenderTargetBitmap many a lot snapshot

Tags: uwp

How to take multiple snapshot elements through RenderTargetBitmap?

I'm using the following XAML-code:

```html
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="pin" Height="72" Width="64" Visibility="Visible" >
            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="img"
                   Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/pin_cluster.png"/>
            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="emp"
                   Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Icons/pin.png"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="cluster_count"
                   Text="99"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextAlignment="Center"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="#FFF7F7F7" Margin="37,5,0,52" Height="15"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stack" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="100" Height="100"/>
        <Image Width="78" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And example C#-code:

```cs
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsStart = true;
    int tt = 0;
    foreach (var element in stack.Children)
    {
        var imgUI = element as Image;
        img.UpdateLayout();
        imgUI.UpdateLayout();
        var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        cluster_count.Text = tt++.ToString();
        if (tt % 2 == 0)
            await bitmap.RenderAsync(pin);
        else
            await bitmap.RenderAsync(emp);
        imgUI.Source = bitmap;
        bitmap = null;
        pin.UpdateLayout();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

The essence of the code it is redraw one or many image from grid on different image source. In particular, it is planned to use as pins on map.

The problem is that the multiple use of RenderTargetBitmap with RenderAsync leads to overlapping snapshots.

As you can seen from the code i'm trying free memory of image grid, through garbage collector and update of layouts, but all without success.

Comment: Why not just set `Source` for these images? I didn't see any reason to use `RenderTargetBitmap`.

Comment: Need many images add on map control. Images can be static and dynamic with variable textbox. I think just easer change UIcontrol and get snapshot this image for icon on map